# H2O cluster not working (misreads node ip)

Tags: hadoop, h2o

I am trying to run H2O cluster on 4 nodes. I ran the following command:

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 4 -network 192.168.56.0/24 -mapperXmx 2g -output hdfsOutputDirName
```

But, it contacts an ip not listed on my flatfile and fails to come up,

```
H2O node 192.168.56.124:54321 requested flatfile
H2O node 192.168.56.101:54321 requested flatfile
H2O node 192.168.56.125:54321 requested flatfile
H2O node 192.168.56.123:54321 requested flatfile
```

The ip of my 4th node is 192.168.56.122 not 192.168.56.101. Is there an issue with using the `-network` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is correct.

YARN really did dispatch one of the containers to 192.168.56.101 or that message would not have appeared.